# Batch Extract with 7Zip

Tags: 7-zip

I receive a single zip folder with multiple zip folders inside it.  Each individual zip folder contains one file.  Is there a way to extract all of them in one step?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7, Vista, XP, etc.

From the command line:

```
cd folder
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`dir *.7z /s/b`) do 7za x %i
```

From a batch file, double the % signs:

```
cd folder
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir *.7z /s/b`) do (
    @echo extracting %%i
    7za x %%i
)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 for you. This does require the command-line version of 7-Zip though.